# How to read the "local.trace" file generated by tensorflow summary callback?

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorboard

I could not find a way to read the `local.trace` file that gets generated after I fit my model with a summary callback enabled:

```
LOG_DIR = "/tmp/tfds-keras/tl"+str(counter)
model.fit(
    dataset,
    validation_data=dataset_test,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=DATASET_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE//10,
    validation_steps=20,
    callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=LOG_DIR, update_freq=100
                                            )],
)
counter=counter+1
```

The file gets saved to:

```
└── tl1
    ├── events.out.tfevents.1568229131.aurora01
    ├── events.out.tfevents.1568229134.aurora01.profile-empty
    └── plugins
        └── profile
            └── 2019-09-11_15-12-14
                └── local.trace
```

And visual inspection shows that it displays information of operations executed by the gpu.

```
...
'tf_data_parallel_interleave_worker_pool^P<80><AE><90><E5>^M"J^Z*edge_2139_metrics/acc/Identity::MemcpyDtoHH<C0><80><D8><F1><DB>^DP<C0><96><B1>^BZ^P
^Elabel^R^G4 bytes">^Z^^edge_2137_loss/mul::MemcpyDtoHH<80><A0><83><F5><DB>^DP<C0><9F><AB>^CZ^P
^Elabel^R^G4 bytes"^A^P^A^Z%edge_2130_IteratorGetNext::MemcpyHtoDH<C0><9D><EE><D7><C9>^DP<C0><FC><F0>5Z^U
^Elabel^R^L393216 bytes"^A^Z$edge_287_IteratorGetNext::MemcpyHtoDH<80><BD><99><DB><C9>^DP<80><D4><CB>1Z^R
^Elabel^R       256 bytes"^A^Z2edge_1494_loss/dense_loss/num_elements::MemcpyHtoDH<80><D9>ש<DB>^DP<80><92><F4>^AZ^P
^Elabel^R^G4 bytes"^A^Z&edge_1497_metrics/acc/Size::MemcpyHtoDH<80><F4>Ŭ<DB>^DP<C0><96><B1>^BZ^P
...
```

I have tried to open the `tl1` folder on tensorboard and although it displays a profile tab, nothing can be visualized.

Comment: Did you find out?

Comment: I dont think I did and I moved on.
But now I suspect that this is a nvprof generated file and you can probably read it with nvvp (NVIDIA Visual Profiler).
Unfortunately I don't have a trace file to test this out.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow generate five files in my scenario, they are:

- .input_pipeline.pb
- .kernel_stats.pb
- .overview_page.pb
- .tensorflow_stats.pb
- .trace.json.gz

The `pb` files could be converted to `pbtxt` or `txt` files using package `tensorflow.python.platform.gfile`.

The `.trace.json.gz` could be extracted to a `json` file. You can read it by any language. The file format is [Trace Event Format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/edit) by Chromium.